# How to select all details from 2 tables (a,b) without repeating values of a column in one table(a).?? What is the codeigniter query for this?

Tags: sql, codeigniter, mysqli

Im having 2 tables lets say tableA and tableB..

tableA

```
Aid name phone email
 1   n1   p1    e1 
 2   n2   p2    p3
```

tableB

```
  id  column1 column2  Aid 
   1    v1       val1    1 
   2    v2       val2    1
   3    v3       val3    2
```

I need to get result as

```
 name count phone  email  
   n1    2     p1    e1 
   n2    1     p2    e2
```

I need codeigniter query

Comment: Add DISTINCT or switch to an IN-Subquery or switch to to a Correlated EXISTS-Subquery

Answer (score 0):

Base on your given example, and let's assume you are using MySQL, and CI query builder and I think this is what you looking for.

```
 $this->db->select('tableA.name, COUNT(tableA.id) AS totalCount, 
   tableA.phone,tableA.email')
         ->from('tableA')
         ->join('tableB', 'tableB.aid= tableA.id')
         ->group_by('tableA.id');
     $result = $this->db->get();
```

Hope this helps!